# Filter array of objects based on array of strings on object's property

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of objects like:

`let food = [apple, orange, peach, pear]`.

Each object looks something like this:

```
let apple : Fruit = [
  name: "Apple",
  colors: ["red", "yellow", "green", "orange"]
]
```

I have another array of strings that the `food` array should be filtered with:

`let avoid = ["red", "yellow"]`

I want to create a new array from the `food` array, with `Fruit` objects that *do not contain* any of the `colors` in the `avoid` array. So in this case, `Apple` would not be in the food array because it contains both `red` and `yellow`.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `Fruit` represent? A type, a protocol, a typealias? *something like* is not helpful.

Comment: var names start with a lowercase letter. Type names start with an uppercase letter. `apple` is a var `Fruit` is a type. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't given any definition of `Fruit` object, I'm considering one for reference.

```
struct Fruit {
    let name: String
    let colors: [String]
}
```

Creating the `food` array,

```
let apple = Fruit(name: "Apple", colors: ["red", "yellow", "green", "orange"])
let orange = Fruit(name: "Orange", colors: ["red", "green", "orange"])
let peach = Fruit(name: "Peach", colors: ["green", "orange"])
let pear = Fruit(name: "Pear", colors: [ "green"])
let food = [apple, orange, peach, pear]
```

To `filter` the `food` array using `avoid` array, we can use `Set` `intersection` method, i.e.

```
let avoid = ["red", "yellow"]
let filteredFruits = food.filter { return Set($0.colors).intersection(avoid).isEmpty }
print(filteredFruits.map({ $0.name })) //["Peach", "Pear"]
```

`filteredFruits` will contain objects - `pear` and `peach`

Comment: I would make the initial assumption that `Fruit` is a struct not a class as it has no need to be a class in this example and struct should always be the first choice for types.

Comment: This is just an example. As I already said he might have taken it a `class` too. We aren't sure about that. `class` and `struct` always depends upon your use case.

Comment: Exactly, which is why struct should be the choice here. Since it is what you would choose for this example if you were writing it. Nothing here needs a class.

Comment: Perfect -- this is what I meant :) And yeah, I forgot to give an example of the `Fruit` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
let res= food.filter(function(fruit) {
  return !fruit.colors.some(r=> avoid.indexOf(r) >= 0)
})
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!